# MVVM Cross Approach to Login/Authentication

Tags: authentication, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am just getting into MVVM Cross. I am now tackling how to code the login code in a cross-platform/MVVM Cross way.

My original approach was to use Xamarin.Auth but this component cannot be used in PCL projects which (correct me if I am wrong) means I need to write code for each platform (Android, iOS, Windows Phone). This isn't the MVVM/MVVM Cross way of doing things.

Whats a MVVM Cross way of handling login and authentication? How have you handled user login in the past?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different way for implementing authentification.
The login process is often based on a simple HttpRequest providing the credentials (username and password, a login token, a signed request etc.)
So you can simply do the request via `HttpClient`and store the resulting session token (or whatever you receive) on your own.

But of course, you can also use Xamarin.Auth inside a PCL.
There's a great tutorial about it: http://www.joesauve.com/using-xamarin-auth-with-xamarin-forms/

This tutorial makes use of `Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService`. If you don't Xamarin.Forms then you need to use `Mvx` instead as you are using MvvmCross. But the principle stays the same.

Comment: Can you expand your answer with what is needed to change following "MvvmCross way" ?